# finding connecting pattern / adv partition to get latest value using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I am new to pyspark. Some one please help to get the answer.

Problem:

I have dataframe which contains two columns one var_x and another var_y.

[image: Data Frame]

In above data from first I need to partition and sort to bring all connected pattern variables at one place, I want to explain bit more using one example: Here if you observer var_x value updates in var_y z2146 becomes -> y3498, again y3498 becomes -> B5216, again B5216 becomes -> B6849, finally B6849 -> C9965.

So latest value for this connected variables is C9965, similary with other variables. Expected output looks likes below.

[image: DataFrame2]

Here main problem I unable to partition data based on connecting pattern variables. Some one please help me to get the answer.

Comment: @Kafels could you please look into above query as well.  I have tried several ways but no luck. I feel you are the right person for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get your solution by using `RDD`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('Z2146', 'y3498'),
    ('A2286', 'C4955'),
    ('y3498', 'B5216'),
    ('B5216', 'B6849'),
    ('D7777', 'E8849'),
    ('C4955', 'Q7658'),
    ('B6849', 'C9965'),
], ('var_x', 'var_y'))

# Creating an incremental id to use later
df = df.withColumn('increasing_id', f.monotonically_increasing_id())

# Set to this column a value that would partition your data. If you don't have,
# leave as 1, but may have performance issues depending your dataset size
df = df.withColumn('partition', f.lit(1))


def transform(rows):
    mapper, group_id = {}, 0
    for row in rows:
        increasing_id, var_x, var_y = row

        if var_x in mapper:
            group = mapper.get(var_x)
            yield increasing_id, var_x, var_y, group
            mapper.pop(var_x)
            mapper[var_y] = group
        else:
            mapper[var_y] = group_id
            yield increasing_id, var_x, var_y, group_id
            group_id += 1


# Creating a new column with `RDD` that contains which group your row belongs to
df_linked = (df
             .rdd
             .map(lambda row: (row.partition, (row.increasing_id, row.var_x, row.var_y)))
             .groupByKey()
             .flatMapValues(transform)
             .map(lambda row: row[1])
             .toDF('increasing_id long, var_x string, var_y string, group int'))
# +-------------+-----+-----+-----+
# |increasing_id|var_x|var_y|group|
# +-------------+-----+-----+-----+
# |   8589934592|Z2146|y3498|    0|
# |  25769803776|y3498|B5216|    0|
# |  34359738368|B5216|B6849|    0|
# |  60129542144|B6849|C9965|    0|
# |  17179869184|A2286|C4955|    1|
# |  51539607552|C4955|Q7658|    1|
# |  42949672960|D7777|E8849|    2|
# +-------------+-----+-----+-----+

# Getting the last `var_y` from each group
w = (Window.partitionBy('group')
     .orderBy(f.col('increasing_id').asc())
     .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing))
df_latest = df_linked.select('var_x', 'var_y', f.last('var_y').over(w).alias('Latest'))
df_latest.orderBy('group', 'increasing_id').show()
# +-----+-----+------+
# |var_x|var_y|Latest|
# +-----+-----+------+
# |Z2146|y3498| C9965|
# |y3498|B5216| C9965|
# |B5216|B6849| C9965|
# |B6849|C9965| C9965|
# |A2286|C4955| Q7658|
# |C4955|Q7658| Q7658|
# |D7777|E8849| E8849|
# +-----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the exact answer in the pyspark, but I  addressed above one with python.

Steps: I converted Var x and Var y varibles as a dictonary. then I used below code to get the latest values.

```
d = {'Z2146':'y3498', 'y3498':'B5216', 'B5216':'B6849', 'B6849':'C9965', 'A2286':'C4955', 'C4955':'Q7658', 'D7777':'E8849'}

keys = list(d.keys())
values = list(d.values())

n = len(d.keys())
print(n)
while (n>0):
    for i,j in d.items():
        if(j in keys):
            d[i]=d[j]
    n = n-1
print(d)
```

Saved output it as another dictionary, finally converted back to data frame column  in pyspark.

If any one want to improve my code either in python or pyspark. Feel free to do and post it.

Comment: @Kafels please have a look my answer, I tried with python. please check and suggest me there could be a possible to convert above code into pyspark.